# CKEDITOR vertical scrollbar Xpages

Tags: ckeditor, scrollbar, xpages

I need to enable vertical scroolbar into my CKEDITOR classic RT control...
So I have used this CSS

.cke_show_borders {
    overflow-y: scroll; // vertical scrollbar
    overflow-x: scroll; // horizontal scrollbar
}

But don't work..

Anyone have suggest for me?

Comment: Ok I have found that autoGrow plugin is anbled...

Now I need to understad how delete from startup of CKEDITOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `config.removePlugins` ([docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins)):

```
config.removePlugins = 'autogrow';
```

Alternatively, modify `config.plugins` ([docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-plugins)) to select only those that you really need.

Comment: Tnx I have insert into Dojo section GUI of XPages the key/value and word and work well!